# How To Move Row In DataBound DataGrid In C# without Knowing The Object Type

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I have a number of datgridgs that I want to be able to reorder rows for. They are all SortableBindingList<> : List<> types but they contain different objects.  I tried casting the DataGridView's DataSource to `SortableBindingList<object>` to `.RemoveAt()` & `.Insert()` but the cast failed.  I tried to pass the object type into the function using a `Type` but that failed.

```
Type objType;
...
var x = (SortableBindingList<objType>) dataGridView.DataSource;
```

but that doesn't work either, nether does 'typeof(objType)`.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Generic types have to be declared at compile time, not run time. You may have to use the non-generic IEnumerable instead.

Comment: would i cast my `SortableBindingList<>` to an IEnumerable?   I don't know why this is tricky - I know the list class - why can't it treat the things inside it as objects for the sake of adding or removing?   When I look at an object cast to object in the debugger it still knows what the object was.  Is there a way to get recast an object to the object type?  (i.e. Foo x = new Foo(); var y = (object) x;  -> some magic to make y into a Foo automatically?)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I can do this with dynamic types.

```
            dynamic list = dgv.DataSource;
            var item = list[rowIndexFromMouseDown];
            list.RemoveAt(rowIndexFromMouseDown);
            if (rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop == -1)
                list.Add(item);
            else list.Insert(rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop, item);
```